# Get the specific count of a delimiter in a string in Xpath

Tags: xpath

I have a string containing values delimited by a separator:

```
<test>xtre_ghtr_juwed_tsdew_fgus_</test>
```

How would I get the specific count of the underscore character when providing a specific substring, for example if searching for xtre return 1, ghtr = 2, fgus = 5? Is there an existing function that could be leveraged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like:

```
index-of(tokenize("<test>xtre_ghtr_juwed_tsdew_fgus_</test>", "_"),"fgus")
```

which in this case should return `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via below way. If you are using Python, you can use the `lxml` library to parse the `XML` document and use the `xpath` method to evaluate the XPath expression.

```
from lxml import etree

xml_string = "<test>xtre_ghtr_juwed_tsdew_fgus_</test>"
xml_doc = etree.fromstring(xml_string)

substring = "xtre"
xpath_expr = f"string-length(substring-before(substring-after(//test, '{substring}'), '_'))"
count = int(xml_doc.xpath(xpath_expr))

print(f"Count of underscores after '{substring}': {count}")
```

***OutPut***

```
Count of underscores after 'xtre': 1
```

You can read more about [here](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#parsing-from-strings-and-files)

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I should have asked for xpath-only (1.0/2.0/3.0) solutions. Is there a way to get the desired output without the python library?

Comment: What is your desire output ?